# Default AsyncStorage values in a Detox test

Tags: detox

I'm wondering how to default AsyncStorage values in React Native for a Detox test.

I have a welcome modal which shows when the user firsts login. We control whether to show the modal by storing an AsyncStorage value. Since our tests launch different instances of the apps (with different settings), I'm looking for a way to default a value before a test begins.

I shortly investigated using a jest mock but not sure that's the right approach because I don't want to mock all of `.getItem`, I just want to mock it for this specific value that is stored.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As per mocking: would you consider replacing your async-storage with a mocked implementation that is in fact rewired into a file on your host or even a settings server? https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md

Comment: Hey again, could you perhaps describe how that value is set ahead of time in your apps, regardless of testing?

Answer (score 1):

I do it by opening the app with a dynamic link like this:

`myapp://example/?action=setAsyncStorage&key=someKey&value=someValue`

The app has a dynamiclink handler that recognizes this dynamic link and sets a value into AsyncStorage.